# Нужна форма получения данных о лайках под записью

Tags: php, вконтакте

Есть форма:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="Ссылка на страницу в вк"/>
  <input type="text" name="wall" value="Ссылка на запись в вк"/>
  <input type="submit" name="go" value="Проверить"/>
</form>
```

Теперь обрабатывает форму так:
Нажимаем на кнопку "Проверить", и отправляем 2 строки ("id", "wall") POST запросом на php.
Теперь вопрос:
Как сделать так, что бы в записи вк ("wall"), прошла проверка, лайкнул ли пользователь ("id") запись ("wall")?


Напоминаю: Что бы все это проверилось php методом!
Вообще, возможно ли это?

Comment: Покажите код, который вы написали на PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать так, что бы в записи вк ("wall"), прошла проверка, лайкнул
>   ли пользователь ("id") запись ("wall")?

Для подобного есть метод [likes.isLiked](https://vk.com/dev/likes.isLiked).
С помощью него и можно проверить.

Пример запроса:

> https://api.vk.com/method/likes.isLiked?user_id=18392410&type=post&owner_id=-36147615&item_id=551579&access_token=yourtoken